# Stored Procedure ; Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: stored-procedures, insert

> > when i insert data this error occur sub-query return more than 1 value this is not permitted when the subquery follows = , >=,>,<,<=

```
               INSERT INTO OrderItem
                    (               
                     OrderItemGuid                                 ,
                     OrderId                                       ,
                     ProductId                                     ,
                     Quantity                                      ,
                     UnitPriceInclTax                              ,
                     UnitPriceExclTax                              ,
                     PriceInclTax                                  ,
                     PriceExclTax                                  ,
                     DiscountAmountInclTax                         ,
                     DiscountAmountExclTax                         ,
                     OriginalProductCost                           ,
                     AttributeDescription                          ,
                     AttributesXml                                 ,
                     DownloadCount                                 ,
                     IsDownloadActivated                           ,
                     LicenseDownloadId                             ,
                     ItemWeight                                    ,
                     RentalStartDateUtc                            ,
                     RentalEndDateUtc                              ,
                     CreatedOnUtc                                  ,
                     ProductName                                   ,
                     ShortDescription                              ,
                     FullDescription                               ,
                     PictureId

                    )                 

                    VALUES
                    (                                                                         
                     NULL                                         ,                     
                     NULL                                         ,                      
                     (SELECT  ProductId FROM ShoppingCartItem WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId )                         ,
                     (SELECT  Quantity FROM ShoppingCartItem WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId)                               ,
                     (SELECT  SUM(P.Price*SC.Quantity) AS UnitPriceInclTax FROM ShoppingCartItem SC INNER JOIN Product P ON SC.Id = P.Id WHERE SC.CustomerId =  @CustomerId AND SC.ProductId = @ProductId )                                        ,
                     (SELECT  (P.Price) AS UnitPriceExclTax FROM ShoppingCartItem SC INNER JOIN Product P ON SC.Id = P.Id WHERE SC.CustomerId = @CustomerId AND SC.ProductId = @ProductId)                                         ,                                                
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     NULL                                          ,
                     @CreatedOnUtc                                 ,                        
                     (SELECT (P.Name) AS ProductName FROM ShoppingCartItem SC INNER JOIN Product P ON SC.Id = P.Id WHERE SC.CustomerId =  @CustomerId AND SC.ProductId = @ProductId)                                               ,
                     (SELECT (P.ShortDescription) AS ShortDescription   FROM ShoppingCartItem SC INNER JOIN Product P ON SC.Id = P.Id WHERE SC.CustomerId =  @CustomerId AND SC.ProductId = @ProductId)                                        ,
                     (SELECT (P.FullDescription) AS FullDescription FROM ShoppingCartItem SC INNER JOIN Product P ON SC.Id = P.Id WHERE SC.CustomerId =  @CustomerId AND SC.ProductId = @ProductId)                                          ,
                     (SELECT (PM.PictureId) AS PictureId FROM ShoppingCartItem SC INNER JOIN Product_Picture_Mapping PM ON SC.Id = PM.Id WHERE SC.CustomerId =  @CustomerId AND SC.ProductId = @ProductId)                                      


                    )
```

I get the following error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly what the error message says:  one or more of your subqueries is returning multiple values instead of a single value.  That being said, why are you doing repeated subqueries against the same table?  Why not just select all the values you need from the `ShoppingCartItem` table directly?  (i.e. `INSERT INTO OrderItem ( columns ) SELECT (columns) FROM ShoppingCartItem`)

Comment: It's Working....Thanks a lot @LittleBobbyTables